# Which deployment of Apps Script do Sheets custom functions use?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with some code in a bound Apps Script. The code contains some functions that are used in a nightly trigger, and some custom functions used in sheet formulas.

I'm trying to have a sane development process for this, and to decouple saving code from releasing it - so I have a "production" deployment, and the trigger runs code from that deployment - when the code is ready, I update the production deployment with the new version (I use `clasp` to manage this process). This works fine.

However, I don't know **which deployment of my Apps Script code does Google Sheets use when running custom functions**? Does it always use code from the `@HEAD` deployment? Is there a way to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On bounded scripts custom functions use the head deployment, on add-ons use the version specified in the Google Workspace Marketplace Configuration page..

Comment: Thanks Rubén! So do I understand correctly that, if I want to control which code my custom functions use, I need to publish the code as some sort of private add-on in the Marketplace?

Comment: @jkff  It depend on what do you mean by "control which code" and your personal preferences and circumstances.

Comment: Basically I don't want simply saving the code in the editor to immediately lead to the custom functions in the spreadsheet using that code. I want to be able to control which version of the code is released to be used by custom functions in the spreadsheet - ideally it would be just a "deploy" button or something like that.